# running Android emulator without internet access

Tags: android, android-emulator

can the Android emulator run without an internet connection?

I'd like to develop during my commute and won't have internet access.  please advise if this can be achieved

thanks

Comment: The emulator will run fine without an Internet connection. Please note that Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions.

Comment: not a programming question

Comment: Discussing the run-time requirements of a development environment seems like a programming question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You should download all neccessary libraries and helperclasses first though.
Google Maps or Google Cloud Message, etc wont work of course.

Comment: I have everything downloaded but each time i run the emulator it tries to connect to the net resulting in a dns error.  how do i stop the emulator from trying to connect?

Comment: Maybe Post/Get requests in your application? Any files that need to be downloaded like jQuery? I seriously can't tell you.

Comment: im only running the basic hello world example from the Android site.  the emulator only runs if connected to net.

Answer (score 0):

Android Emulator runs without any Internet connection until and unless your app needs internet access for fetching data.